# How to know WCF progress transmission?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I have a WP8 app and use WCF-service with it. All is nice, but I do not know - how can I quess about progress of transmission huge amount of data? It 5 mb about.

I have only *async() and *completed() methods. Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without extending WCF you could chunk up the data and then update your interface as you download each chunk then when you receive all the pieces then assembly them when you are complete.